# Display Intellij Compilation warning

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, compiler-warnings

I'm running a Scala application using the Scala plugin, right at the end of the compilation phase IntelliJ shows me some compilation warnings but the second the application start running all the warnings at the message window get overridden by the application result, logs etc. Is there another place where I can see the compilation results  or some other way to read them inside IntelliJ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler warnings are displayed in the **Messages** tool window, application output is displayed in **Run** or **Debug** tool window.

You can switch to the **Messages** tool window to see the compiler warnings.

Note that IDE performs Build before Run, if you have already built the project and observed the warnings, the next Build will not produce any compiler warnings since the code is already compiled and compiler doesn't run again without any changes in the code.

To see the warnings again make some change in the code and invoke **Run**. The warnings will appear again in Messages (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>).

If there are no warnings/errors reported by the compiler (because your code is clean or because the code was already compiled during the previous run), **Messages** tool window will not appear.